# 別フォルダのphpファイルに飛ばすことってできますか？

Tags: php

form action =""

の飛ばす先を記述したフォルダではなく、別フォルダに飛ばすことはできますかね？

Comment: 「別フォルダのphpファイルに飛ばす」というのが曖昧なので、どういう挙動を指すのか具体的に記述していただけますか。formでsubmitしたときにどうなって欲しいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/-foo--+--bar--+--baz.php ←参照元
       |       +--  :
       |
       +-hoge--+--fuga.php ←参照先
               +--  :
```

こういう構成を例にすると、

```
<form action="../hoge/fuga.php">
```

や

```
<form action="/foo/hoge/fuga.php">
```

とすればよいです